# Government versus Private Institute as a Faculty in India

Tags: academic-life, india

I am from India. I have two different offers for Assistant professor (computer science) positions in India. The one of the institute is government funded and second is private college.

The main advantage of government college (or semi government) is job security and no work pressure as per my observation in India. I want to join this institute but there is one problem NIRF ranking ([link](https://www.nirfindia.org/2020/Ranking2020.html))  of this institute is like 100 (getting low from last 4-5 years) but of private college is with in 40 (as per last 5 years)

My goal is to join  a college where there is a growth in terms of research and teaching. On the basis of this criteria I am not sure which institute I should join as a faculty member. Suppose that the only thing which I care is research and teaching then kindly suggest me which one will be good for me.

I am in confused which would be a better institute to join as a faculty member.

I know it is not possible to guess future but it is better to take decision on the basis of some analysis.